# Bootstrap Drop Down Menu Causes Focus to Shift to Top of Page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap drop down menu.  When I select a value from the drop down menu, the focus shifts to the top of the page.  The class options for the drop down menu are as follows:

```
<a class = "btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" data-target = "#">
    <span class = "caret"></span>
</a>
```

jFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W7gbj/).  You'll need to scroll down on the results window to the see drop down menu.

What's the best way to remedy this behavior?

Comment: Can you try and remove the #, that will cause that behaviour - http://jsfiddle.net/W7gbj/1/

Comment: @JamesT Hi James, I've tried removing the #, but it doesn't change the behavior

Comment: Okay, I'll look further into it. My apologies

Comment: In your real code, do you have empty links? that seems to be the reason it's doing it.. for example, if you place javascript::return false; into the href, it seems to stop that jump up to the top because it is no longer calling the same page to reload or looking for an anchor that does not exist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your code you have # anchors.

When someone clicks on this, the browser will go to the top of the page in search for an anchor that does not exist.

Even if you remove the #, the link will think it needs to refresh the page.

If you need the anchor for styling, do something like this:

```
<a href = "javascript:return false;">link text</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W7gbj/7/

Comment: I happened to have a fiddle done up with javascript:void(0), so I threw it in there. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: ahhh javascript:void(0) <runs away with code and hides in corner> lol I didn't know that. Now I feel guilty lol. Thanks brah.

Comment: Either works in most cases. There are a number of discussions on SO about which to use.

Comment: I had actually added an event.preventDefault under the "btn dropdown-toggle" onclick event in the bootstrap.js file.  I didn't see that the individual drop down options had their hrefs pointing to #s.  Sometimes the easiest answers are right in front of you

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works but there is a second issue with long selection lists. If the drop down has many items, eg countries, then the user can scroll up or down to select one. The whole page scrolls. The scroll position then stays at that position after the user makes a selection.

I fixed this by applying the accepted answer and by also adding a:

```
@ViewChild('toggleButton') toggleButton: ElementRef;
```

property on the toggle button and then calling:

```
this.toggleButtton.nativeElement.focus();
```

when a selection was made. I know using nativeElement is not recommended for Web Worker reasons, but I'm not using a web worker so it is a solution for me.

Using Bootstrap 4.1.0.